# How is < a syntax error?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, friend

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename E>
class SNode{
    E elem;
    SNode<E>* next;
    friend class SLINKEDList <E>;
};

template <typename E>
class SLinkedList { // a singly linked list
public:
    SLinkedList(); // empty list constructor
    ~SLinkedList(); // destructor
    bool empty() const; // is list empty?
    const E& front() const; // return front element
    void addFront(const E& e); // add to front of list
    void removeFront(); // remove front item list
private:
    SNode<E>* head; // head of the list
};
template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::SLinkedList() // constructor
    : head(NULL) { }
template <typename E>
bool SLinkedList<E>::empty() const // is list empty?
{
    return head == NULL;
}
template <typename E>
const E& SLinkedList<E>::front() const // return front element
{
    return head−>elem;
}
template <typename E>
SLinkedList<E>::~SLinkedList() // destructor
{
    while (!empty()) removeFront();
}
template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::addFront(const E& e) { // add to front of list
    SNode<E>* v = new SNode<E>; // create new node
    v−>elem = e; // store data
    v−>next = head; // head now follows v
    head = v; // v is now the head
}
template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::removeFront() { // remove front item
    SNode<E>* old = head; // save current head
    head = old−>next; // skip over old head
    delete old; // delete the old head
}
int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

I copied this node code from my Data structures book (Goodman) and it has errors, but I'm unsure why. I did try manually typing it to see if it was a character encoding issue, but it doesn't seem to be so.
I also tried defining SLinkedLists, but that didn't change the results.
Errors:

Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '<'

Error   2   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Comment: `SLINKEDList` has not been defined as a template class in that file.  I'm assuming that's what `SLINKEDList` is, but the compiler can't assume.

Comment: Defining and recompiling SLinkedList does not help.

Comment: When the compiler reaches the line with your error, `SLINKEDList` has not been defined as a template class.  You must define it **before** you use it.

Answer (score 2):

In your *original* code, there is no `SLINKEDList` defined anywhere in that file, nor should it be in the only included file, `iostream`.

In fact `g++` also complains, but with a different error:

```
qq.cpp:8:15: error: ‘SLINKEDList’ is not a class template
    friend class SLINKEDList <E>;
                 ^
```

My advice would be to include whatever header files or code it takes to define `SLINKEDList`, that should fix your immediate problem.

In your *updated* code, you define it, but *after* you use it, so you still have the same problem - it's not defined where it should be. In any case `SLINKEDList` is *not* the same as `SLinkedList` so you need to fix that as well.

You can do that by chaanging:

```
template <typename E>
class SNode{
    E elem;
    SNode<E>* next;
    friend class SLINKEDList <E>;
};
```

into:

```
template <typename E> class SLinkedList;
template <typename E> class SNode{
    E elem;
    SNode<E>* next;
    friend class SLinkedList <E>;
};
```

Comment: Defining and recompiling SLinkedList does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `<E>` from your friend declaration.

```
friend class SLINKEDList;
```

If you wonder why consider reading [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends).

Answer (score 1):

This code has a number of problems.

At least in my opinion, `SNode` should really be a nested class inside of `SLinkedList` (since, among other things, nothing outside of the linked list class has any business knowing it even exists). Second, it attempts to declare a class named `SLINKDEDList` as a friend, but no such class exists in the code--it should be `SLinkedList` (C++ is case sensitive). Third, the friend declaration should just be of `SLinkedList`, not `SlinkedList<E>`.

If you nest the node class inside the linked list class, however, you don't need a friend declaration at all, so the result is something like this:

```
template <typename E>
class SLinkedList { // a singly linked list
    struct SNode{
        E elem;
        SNode *next;
    };
public:
    SLinkedList(); // empty list constructor
    ~SLinkedList(); // destructor
    bool empty() const; // is list empty?
    const E& front() const; // return front element
    void addFront(const E& e); // add to front of list
    void removeFront(); // remove front item list
private:
    SNode *head; // head of the list
};
```

You also have a few places where you have something like `v− > elem`. This *needs* to be changed to something like `v->elem` to work. Although you can add more spaces before the `-` or after the `>`, you *must* not have a space between the `-` and `>`. It must be typed as `->`, not `- >` to be recognized as the "pointer to" operator.